# Problema com relacionamento ManyToMany - Java

Tags: java

Boa noite gente, estava fazendo uma tabela que relaciona os médicos e quantos pacientes eles têm, mas na hora do print só vem os médicos, não vem com a Lista de pacientes.

Classs Paciente:

```
package entity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Paciente implements Comparable<Paciente>{

private Integer idPaciente;
private String nomePaciente;
private List<Medico> medicos;

public Paciente() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public Paciente(Integer idPaciente, String nomePaciente, List<Medico> medicos) {
    super();
    this.idPaciente = idPaciente;
    this.nomePaciente = nomePaciente;
    this.medicos = medicos;
}

public Paciente(Integer idPaciente, String nomePaciente) {
    super();
    this.idPaciente = idPaciente;
    this.nomePaciente = nomePaciente;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Paciente [idPaciente=" + idPaciente + ", nomePaciente=" + nomePaciente + ", medicos=" + medicos + "]";
}

public Integer getIdPaciente() {
    return idPaciente;
}

public void setIdPaciente(Integer idPaciente) {
    this.idPaciente = idPaciente;
}

public String getNomePaciente() {
    return nomePaciente;
}

public void setNomePaciente(String nomePaciente) {
    this.nomePaciente = nomePaciente;
}

public List<Medico> getMedicos() {
    return medicos;
}

public void setMedicos(List<Medico> medicos) {
    this.medicos = medicos;
}

public void adicionar(Medico m){
    if (medicos==null){
        medicos = new ArrayList<Medico>();
    }
    medicos.add(m);
}

public void remover(Medico m){
    if (medicos!=null){
        if(medicos.contains(m)){
            medicos.remove(medicos.get(medicos.indexOf(m)));
        }else{
            System.out.println("Não encontrado");
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("Medico vazio");
    }
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    Paciente p = (Paciente) obj;
    return this.idPaciente.equals(p.getIdPaciente());
}


@Override
public int compareTo(Paciente p) {
    return this.idPaciente.compareTo(p.getIdPaciente());
}


}
```

Class Medico:

```
package entity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Medico implements Comparable<Medico> {

    private Integer idMedico;
    private String nomeMedico;
    private String especializacao;
    private List<Paciente> pacientes;



    public Medico() {
    }

    public Medico(Integer idMedico, String nomeMedico, String especializacao, List<Paciente> pacientes) {
        super();
        this.idMedico = idMedico;
        this.nomeMedico = nomeMedico;
        this.especializacao = especializacao;
        this.pacientes = pacientes;
    }

    public Medico(Integer idMedico, String nomeMedico, String especializacao) {
        super();
        this.idMedico = idMedico;
        this.nomeMedico = nomeMedico;
        this.especializacao = especializacao;
    }

    public Medico(List<Paciente> pacientes) {
        super();
        this.pacientes = pacientes;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Médico [idMedico=" + idMedico + ", nomeMedico=" + nomeMedico + ", especializacao=" + especializacao
                + "]";
    }

    public Integer getIdMedico() {
        return idMedico;
    }

    public void setIdMedico(Integer idMedico) {
        this.idMedico = idMedico;
    }

    public String getNomeMedico() {
        return nomeMedico;
    }

    public void setNomeMedico(String nomeMedico) {
        this.nomeMedico = nomeMedico;
    }

    public String getEspecializacao() {
        return especializacao;
    }

    public void setEspecializacao(String especializacao) {
        this.especializacao = especializacao;
    }

    public List<Paciente> getPacientes() {
        return pacientes;
    }

    public void setPacientes(List<Paciente> pacientes) {
        this.pacientes = pacientes;
    }

    public void adicionar(Paciente p){
        if (pacientes==null){
            pacientes = new ArrayList<Paciente>();
        }
        pacientes.add(p);
    }

    public void remover(Paciente p){
        if (pacientes!=null){
            if (pacientes.contains(p)){
                pacientes.remove(pacientes.get(pacientes.indexOf(p)));
            }else{
                System.out.println("Nao encontrado o paciente");
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("Lista está vazia.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        Medico m = (Medico) o;
        return this.idMedico.equals(m.getIdMedico());
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Medico m) {
        return this.idMedico.compareTo(m.getIdMedico());
    }
}
```

E o Main:

```
package entity;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Paciente p1 = new Paciente(10,"Stuart");
        Paciente p2 = new Paciente(11, "Lu");
        Paciente p3 = new Paciente(12,"Andre");

        Medico m1 = new Medico(100, "qlqnome1", "otorrinolaringologista");
        Medico m2 = new Medico(101,"qlqnome2", "psiquiatra");

        m1.adicionar(p1);
        m1.adicionar(p2);
        m1.adicionar(p3);
        m2.adicionar(p1);

        System.out.println(m1);
        System.out.println(m2);
    }
}
```

Resultado:

```
Médico [idMedico=100, nomeMedico=qlqnome1, especializacao=otorrinolaringologista]
Médico [idMedico=101, nomeMedico=qlqnome2, especializacao=psiquiatra]
```

Comment: O resultado apresentado não corresponde ao código. Em especial, você diz que o médico `qlqnome1` é `otorrinolaringologista` e o `qlqnome2` é `psquiatra`, mas a sua saída mostra que `roger` é `viado` e que `globinho` é `psiquiatra`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu método `toString()` do médico não está imprimindo a lista de `pacientes`.

Pode fazer a concatenação utilizando `join`, conforme segue:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Médico [idMedico=" + idMedico + 
                 ", nomeMedico=" + nomeMedico + 
                 ", especializacao=" + especializacao + 
                 ", pacientes=" + String.join(", ", pacientes) + "]";
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, na apostila do meu curso estava mandando não colocarmos o Paciente no toString de Medicos, deve estar errado no pdf, obrigado!

Comment: A resposta foi útil? É possível aceitá-la?

Answer (score 0):

Você adiciona os pacientes aos médicos mas não os médicos aos pacientes. A solução mais simples seria fazer isso:

```
m1.adicionar(p1);
p1.adicionar(m1);
m1.adicionar(p2);
p2.adicionar(m1);
m1.adicionar(p3);
p3.adicionar(m1);
m2.adicionar(p1);
p1.adicionar(m2);
```